# DES Example invalid?

Tags: c++, des

The practical example provided on the following web page, does it contain mistakes or is their some unique step that needs to be followed?

http://www.eventid.net/docs/desexample.asp#Example

The results from the 56-bit key does not match values in the permuted 56-bit key.
Following positions: 51, 43, 35, 27 (do no match the same bits)

Could someone confirm this anomaly?

Please do not inform me that DES has been broken, cause I know.

Comment: This is highly unclear (the results from the key?), and the reference is to a *long* document. Quote the relevant part and explain what you mean.

Comment: I did narrow it down. The results from the 56-bit key does not match values in the permuted 56-bit key. Following positions: 51, 43, 35, 27 (do no match the same bits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have that problem in my code with my issued question. So I consider it resolved.
My Key Schedule works like a charm.